# Screenshot local page with Selenium and PhantomJS

Tags: selenium, python-3.x, local, phantomjs, webpage-screenshot

I am using Selenium with PhantomJS as the webdriver in order to render webpages using Python.
The pages are on my local drive.
I need to save a screenshot of the webpages.
Right now, the pages all render completely black.
The code works perfect on non-local webpages.

Is there a way to specify that the page is local?
I tried this:
driver.get("file://...
but it did not work.

Thanks!

Comment: What about running a simple [Python http server](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) and treating the files as not local?

Answer (score 1):

I feel silly now.
I needed another forward slash
driver.get("file:///